# selenium webdriver can't find element

Tags: html, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, element

I use selenium webdriver last version.

Selenium can't find element (input field). This is html code:

```
<input id="findPath" class="pathCom" type="text" style="width: 100%; 
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" name="$path$conFind" 
value="find" data-ctl="["TextInput"]">
```

I use such selenium code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='findPath']")).sendKeys("find");
```

I have also try find by id or css locator. I set wait before this code like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(" driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='findPath']")).sendKeys("find");")));
```

I have tried to use Selenium IDE, and it found this element. I have no idea that is wrong with webdriver.
Does anyone was faced with such problem?

Comment: Try removing the starting "." and use "//input[@id='findPath']" only.

Comment: I have tried this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thats not the right way of using **sendkeys()** in a `WebDriverWait` statement,

you can try this,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='findPath']"))).sendKeys("find");
```

if you have no use for **wait** variable,you can avoid it as follows

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='findPath']"))).sendKeys("find");
```

if the above statement works,using **id** will definitely work and it improves your **code's performance** as well..

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("findPath"))).sendKeys("find");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is because of a very simple mistake. You have included a period in your xpath

Your Code-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='findPath']")).sendKeys("find");
```

Correct code-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='findPath']")).sendKeys("find");
```

Let me know if it working or not!